# Wordpress & Vue & Nuxt - Integration - wp_enqueue_script

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an existing website where I am gradually replacing the html/css interfaces with Vue technology. So now I have pages with two logics

1. Pages completely in vue
2. Pages with html/css parts and vue parts.

Currently I am using Vue (without Nuxt) with success to do this migration. In my wordpress theme I load vue scripts as follows

```
wp_register_script('vue-app', $directory_uri . '/js/app.js', array(), $version, true);
wp_enqueue_script('vue-app');
```

In order to improve my project I am switching to Nuxt. But I can't keep the same logic of integration. Nuxt does not create a unique app.js. Nuxt is generating a whole bunch of files and I cannot load them synchronously. Neither in build nor in dev (hot-module-replacement).

I don't know how to keep my logic 1 and 2 with Nuxt. Do you have any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Nuxt to it's full potential and keep Wordpress, you need to use Wordpress as a headless CMS. Meaning that you may use [Full static](https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static/) and generate all of your pages during build time by reaching to your Wordpress app.

I guess that your current Wordpress + Vue flow is lacking SEO hence why you're trying to reach upon Nuxt. But to my knowledge, you will not be able to just plug it like that with your `wp_register_script`.

Or maybe try to mount it for every one of your routes `.../about`, `.../our-team` etc... Not a wordpress expert tho.

Comment: Thanks Kissu. Of course full nuxt its the aim. But I am looking for an intermediate solution during the migration of all interfaces.

Comment: When you said " try to mount it for every one of your routes" should I only load scrip App.Js and the page to ? Or also all the files generated (client.js, roiuter.js) etc ?